# control CSS margin with javaScript slider

Tags: javascript, css, slider, margins

I am pretty new to JS and Jquery. I created a simple image carousel that reduces the left-margin of the image so the next one slides in.

I want to control the image carousel with a slider. I think the best way would be to control the size of the left-margin in css with the JS slider.
Like I said I am a beginner so I am having trouble coming up with a solution to target the left-margin value and update it live with the slider either positive or negative direction.

ex 
move slider left left-margin reduces move slider right left-margin grows.
any help would be much appreciate.

thank you so much for your help.

I will include the code I have for the image carousel.

```
// image slider////////////////////////

$(function(){
 // config
  var width = 720;
  var animationSpeed = 1000;
  var pause = 3000;
  var currentSlide = 1;

  //cache DOM

  var $slider = $('#slider');
  var $sliderContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
  var $slides = $sliderContainer.find('.slide');

  var interval;



  function startSlider(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      $sliderContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-=' + width}, animationSpeed, function(){
        currentSlide++;
        if (currentSlide === $slides.length){
            currentSlide = 1;
            $sliderContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
        }
      });
    }, pause);
  }

  function stopSlider(){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  $('#slider').on('mouseenter' , stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);

startSlider();

});



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/assets/css/main.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>starter_build</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id = "slider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li class="slide"><img src="public/assets/images/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="public/assets/images/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="public/assets/images/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="public/assets/images/4.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="public/assets/images/5.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="public/assets/images/6.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="public/assets/images/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
      </ul>
    </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./public/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [**range input**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) for your slider and get its value as the user updates it. Then use that value for the left margin on your slider. Here is an example of getting the value of a range input and using it to come up with a string you can use in a `.css()` statement:

```js
$(function(){
  $('input').on('change', function(){
    $('#current-margin').find('span').text($(this).val() + 'px');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="5040" step="720" value="0">

<p id="current-margin">Current margin: <span>0</span></p>
```

You could use something like that (i.e., `$('input').val() + 'px'`) to update your `width` variable when the input changes.

But you'll have to also take care of things like clearing the timeout to restart your timer and updating `currentSlide` based on the input value as well.